# How to find clusters in binary 3D image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, multidimensional-array, 3d, cluster-analysis

I have a binary 3D image, i.e. it contains only 0 and 1. Now I want to find all clusters of 1s (i.e. clusters of voxels containing only value 1). Finally for each cluster I should know the coordinates of the voxels belonging to that cluster.

How can this be done? Of course I can iterate over all voxels but the difficulty is to detect the clusters and extract all voxels inside the cluster.

I want to do this in Matlab.

Comment: If I understood well you want to use [bwconncomp](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwconncomp.html) with the appropriate connectivity levels (i.e. 6, 18 or 26) for 3D cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `regionprops` with the `'PixelIdxList'` attribute. This uses 8-way connected regions by default. It also obtains the linear index which is useful for computation.

Example:

```
A = false(4,4,3);
A(1,1,1) = true;
A(3,3,3) = true;
rp = regionprops(A,'PixelIdxList');

EDU>> A(rp(1).PixelIdxList)

ans =

     1

EDU>> A(rp(2).PixelIdxList)

ans =

     1
```

You can also use `'PixelList'` to get the 3D coords:

```
EDU>> rp = regionprops(A,'PixelList');
EDU>> rp

rp = 

2x1 struct array with fields:
    PixelList

EDU>> rp(1)

ans = 

    PixelList: [1 1 1]

EDU>> rp(2)

ans = 

    PixelList: [3 3 3]
```

Comment: Thank you. What does 8-way connected regions mean? In your example you only have clusters with one voxel. Will it also return coordinates of voxels with clusters with more than one voxel?

Comment: Usually when you want to find contiguous regions, you have to specify the connectivity. It can either be 4-way or 8-way contiguous. 4-way connectivity means it will search up-left-right-down, whereas 8-way will search all 8 pixels surrounding a point. [Here](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/courses/compsci773s1c/lectures/ImageProcessing-html/neighbourhoods.gif)'s a good picture describing it. This  is for the 2D case btw.

Comment: But this is for 2D as you said. Should one not use 16-way for 3D or something like that?

Comment: Yea, my point was just to be aware that there are different kinds of connectivity for contiguous regions. So you need to make sure the default is OK for your application.

Answer (score 0):

This is called connected components analysis.

A simple approach is by seed filling: scan the whole domain systematically; when you meet a '1', visit all '1' neighbors recursively and set them to '0' (to avoid visiting them more times). The top-level visit enumerates all voxels in a cluster. When a cluster has been cleared, continue the search for other '1's.

Beware that this will be stack-intensive, and it can be better to implement an explicit stack for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on rules you wish to employ. And on how is your 3D represented.
Is it a point cloud, or a 2D bitmap using colours to represent depth, or a 
3D array, or what...

You can try clustering them according to planes or in little 3D clouds inside a 3D Space.
If first, slice the 3D space into planes and use 2D clustering algorithm on them.
You will then have clusters for each depth plane, if one exists.
If second, modify the 2D search clustering algorithm to use cubes of space instead of squares of a plane as a frame.
You can even use 2D algorithm on sliced planes, then check surrounding planes to see whether a cluster goes further in 3D space.
But this would be inefficient. I am not a matlab expert, so I cant help you much with implementation,
but maybe there is some toolbox already for doing exactly what you want.
And, of course, how will you do it much depends on how is your image represented in memory.
Maybe you will have to change formats in order to easily and efficiently extract clusters.
Give Google something to do.

Edit:
Just got an idea.
Use proper format and just sort the data.
You should get a list of all adjacent points.
Incorporate the info about coordinates in the input data. Sorting is often faster than connecting.

Comment: I think jucistains solution will do.